# circular import trying to import functorch

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, torch

I tried importing functorch and torch in python 3.9.7

```
import torch
from functorch import vmap, grad
```

and ran into a circular import  issue.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4p/5v2n8wpn58v6xw674tjlss680000gn/T/ipykernel_64234/1530828949.py in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 from functorch import vmap, grad

/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functorch/__init__.py in <module>
      5 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
      6 import torch
----> 7 from . import _C
      8 
      9 # Top-level APIs. Please think carefully before adding something to the

ImportError: cannot import name '_C' from partially initialized module 'functorch' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functorch/__init__.py)
```

Any way around it? Is this a bug in the packages?
Submitting this here since I could not find an easy fix

I tried reinstalling torch and functorch several times. To no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that `functorch` has been deprecated as of PyTorch 2.0. The announcement on their [website](https://pytorch.org/functorch/stable/) says that:

> We’ve integrated functorch into PyTorch. As the final step of the integration, the functorch APIs are deprecated as of PyTorch 2.0. Please use the torch.func APIs instead and see the [migration guide](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/func.migrating.html) and [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/func.html) for more details.

Since you're also importing `torch`, it is most likely causing the circular import errors because that package is also trying to import `functorch`. Since it is deprecated, it is highly recommended that you use `torch.func` instead.

If you want to use `vmap` and `grad`, you can remove the import of `functorch` and use the following instead.

Instead of:

```
functorch.grad
```

Use:

```
torch.func.grad()
```

Instead of:

```
functorch.vmap
```

use:

```
torch.vmap() # or you can use torch.func.vmap()
```

Check their documentation for other migration tips. The link is posted above.